# Optimal reproduction of TikZ figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I am interested in *properly* reproducing the above figure. The red marks are not part of the figure and just for identifying blocks. I am especially interested in the following aspects.

1. The top border of block A should be at the same height as the top border of block B1; its bottom border at the same height as the bottom border of block BK. The same applies for block C.
2. The fork between block A and blocks Bi (i=1,...,K) should be as in the above figure, i.e. enough space for $\vec p(\vec c)$ and in this angular form.
3. Inside block A I want to have text at the top, the bottom and in between.
4. Ideally I am able to set the distance between block B2 and BK.

You find my attempt below. What I don't like about it is:

- Requirement 1 is not perfectly fulfilled. I have to manually set the heights of blocks A and C, and still the boxes are not aligned (probably up to a multiple of `line width`).
- There is too much empty space (two invisible small nodes) between B2 and BK.
- The spacing inside block A is made by hand. Maybe something like `$p_1...$\\$p_2...$\vfill$\vdots$\vfill$p_K...$` could do the job.

[image: My attempt]

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
   \begin{tikzpicture}[
      node distance=0.2cm and 1.2cm,
      small node/.style={rectangle, draw, minimum width=2.5cm, minimum height=1  cm, align=center, fill=lightgray},
      large node/.style={small node, minimum height=5.8cm},
      invisible node/.style={minimum size=0pt, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},
   ]
      % Nodes.
      \node[invisible node] (init) {};
      
      \node[large node, right=of init, align=center] (a) {$p_1p(\vec c\vert\Omega_1)$\\$p_2p(\vec c\vert\Omega_2)$\\[1cm]$\vdots$\\[1cm]$p_Kp(\vec c\vert\Omega_K)$};
      
      \node[invisible node, right=of a] (b) {};
      
      \node[small node, right=of b , draw=none, fill=none] (c3) {};
      \node[small node, above=of c3                      ] (c2) {$\vec r_1^\top \vec p(\vec c)$};
      \node[small node, above=of c2,                     ] (c1) {$\vec r_0^\top \vec p(\vec c)$};
      \node[small node, below=of c3, draw=none, fill=none] (c4) {};
      \node[small node, below=of c4                      ] (c5) {$\vec r_K^\top \vec p(\vec c)$};
      
      \node[large node, right=of c3] (d) {$\kappa^\ast = \arg\min_\kappa u_\kappa$};
      
      \node[invisible node, right=of d] (e) {};
      
      
      % Arrows.
      \draw[->] (init) -- node[anchor=south, pos=0.5] {$\vec c$}         (a);
      
      \draw[  ] (a)    -- node[anchor=south, pos=0.5] {$\vec p(\vec c)$} (b);
      
      \draw[->] (b)    |- node[anchor=south, pos=0.5] {}                 (c1);
      \draw[->] (b)    |- node[anchor=south, pos=0.5] {}                 (c2);
      \draw[->] (b)    |- node[anchor=south, pos=0.5] {}                 (c5);
      
      \draw[->] (c1) -- node[anchor=south]{$u_0(\vec c)$} (c1 -| d.west);
      \draw[->] (c2) -- node[anchor=south]{$u_1(\vec c)$} (c2 -| d.west);
      \draw[->] (c5) -- node[anchor=south]{$u_K(\vec c)$} (c5 -| d.west);
      
      \draw[->] (d) -- node[anchor=south] {$\Omega_{\kappa^\ast}$} (e);
   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should some of this be automatic? I'd start by making `A` high enough so that there will be enough space between `c2` and `c5`. However, if you want that whitespace to be as high as two of those nodes there are ways to let `A` be as high as those nodes. The first and last rows of `A` could be done as labels so that they are just directly at the top/bottom (`label={[below]above:$p_1p(\vec c | \Omega_1)$}`). You could also do this with a `matrix` and use custom row sep.

Comment: You can use `\coordinate` as an invisible node.  Of course, it only has a center anchor.  You can specify a height for `\parbox` or `minipage`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Coordinates have other anchors, too. They're just all in the same place. Or, at least, it is certainly *as if* they have them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a few ideas:

- The middle boxes are drawn first and used as a reference for the big ones (via `ext.positioning-plus` and its `|` in the `of` part of `left` and `right` which makes the new box the total height of the other ones.
- The content of the left box is placed as labels or
- as `dumb labels` which are placed on the same height as the corresponding small boxes.
- The lines are drawn by `horizontal vertical horizontal` (i.e. `-|-`) and `only horizontal first`.
- The various `minimum width` and `minimum height` requirements are set so that the nodes don't look so tight but the left box is also wide enough for its labels. (An automatic approach could be available but this is quicker.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{
  arrows.meta,
  ext.paths.ortho,
  ext.positioning-plus,
  quotes,
}
\tikzset{
  math nodes/.style={execute at begin node=$, execute at end node=$},
  dumb label/.style args={[#1]#2}{label={[{tikz@label@post/.code=,anchor=center,#1}]#2}},
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every box/.style={draw, fill=lightgray, minimum width=+6em},
  small box/.style={every box, minimum height=+2em},
  big box/.style={every box},
  every label/.append style={align=center},
  node distance=2mm and 4em,
  every edge quotes/.append style=math nodes,
]
\node[small box] (c0)                   {$\vec r_0^\top \vec p(\vec c)$};
\node[small box] (c1) [below=    of c0] {$\vec r_1^\top \vec p(\vec c)$};
\node[small box] (cK) [below=4em of c1] {$\vec r_K^\top \vec p(\vec c)$};
%                            ^^^ vertical distance between c1 and ck
\node[big box] (box1) [left=of |(c0)(cK),
  label={[below]above:$p_1p(\vec c \,\vert \Omega_1)$ \\
                      $p_2p(\vec c\, \vert \Omega_2)$},
  label={[above]below:$p_Kp(\vec c \,\vert \Omega_K)$},
]{$\vdots$};
\node[big box] (box2) [right=of |(c0)(cK)]{$\kappa^\ast = \arg\min_\kappa u_\kappa$};

\path[->] (box1.west) edge[<-, "\vec c"'] +(left:x_node_dist)
          [horizontal vertical horizontal, ortho/ratio=.6666]
          (box1) edge (c0)
                 edge["\vec p(\vec c)" very near start] (c1)
                 edge (cK)
          [only horizontal first]
          (c0) edge["u_0(\vec c)"] (box2)
          (c1) edge["u_1(\vec c)"] (box2)
          (cK) edge["u_\kappa(\vec c)"] (box2)
          [line to] % back to --
          (box2.east) edge["\Omega_{\kappa^\ast}"] +(right:x_node_dist)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every box/.style={draw, fill=lightgray, minimum width=+6em},
  small box/.style={every box, minimum height=+2em},
  big box/.style={every box},
  every label/.append style={align=center},
  node distance=2mm and 4em,
  every edge quotes/.append style=math nodes,
]
\node[small box] (c0)                   {$\vec r_0^\top \vec p(\vec c)$};
\node[small box] (c1) [below=    of c0] {$\vec r_1^\top \vec p(\vec c)$};
\node[small box] (cK) [below=4em of c1] {$\vec r_K^\top \vec p(\vec c)$};
%                            ^^^ vertical distance between c1 and ck
\node[big box] (box1) [left=of |(c0)(cK),
  @/.style={dumb label={[at=(\tikzlastnode|-c#1), name=\tikzlastnode#1]%
    $p_{#1}p(\vec c \,\vert \Omega_{#1})$}},
  @/.list={0, 1, K},
]{};
\path (box11) -- node {$\vdots$} (box1K); % or at ($(box11)!.5!(box1K)$)
\node[big box] (box2) [right=of |(c0)(cK)]{$\kappa^\ast = \arg\min_\kappa u_\kappa$};

\path[->] (box1.west) edge[<-, "\vec c"'] +(left:x_node_dist)
          [horizontal vertical horizontal, ortho/ratio=.6666]
          (box1) edge (c0)
                 edge["\vec p(\vec c)" very near start] (c1)
                 edge (cK)
          [only horizontal first]
          (c0) edge["u_0(\vec c)"] (box2)
          (c1) edge["u_1(\vec c)"] (box2)
          (cK) edge["u_\kappa(\vec c)"] (box2)
          [line to] % back to --
          (box2.east) edge["\Omega_{\kappa^\ast}"] +(right:x_node_dist)
;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]
[image]

Comment: That fulfils pretty much everything I wanted. As far as I can tell you wrote a very useful package with TikZ-Ext!